# What is the difference between two FOREACH block codes in Cypher?

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb, opencypher

Are these two blocks actually the same? The goal is to create three nodes with IDs 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Block 1:

```
FOREACH ( i IN [1, 2, 3, 4] | CREATE (n {id : i}) )
```

Block 2:

```
  CREATE (n { prop : [[1, 2], [3, 4]]);

  MATCH (n) FOREACH ( inner_list IN n.prop | FOREACH ( j IN inner_list | CREATE (u { prop : j }) ) );
```

The first method seems simpler to me, and I would go with that one. What would be the advantage of the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two queries here are clearly quite different. The second, which honestly looks very contrived and unnecessarily complex, creates an additional node, as well as changing the property name from `id` to `prop`. In reality, the alternative approach to the first query is much more likely to be something based on use of `UNWIND`. For example:

```
UNWIND [1, 2, 3, 4] AS i
CREATE (n {id: i})
RETURN n
```

I see no advantage to the second query other than as a demonstration of nested `FOREACH` clauses.